# docker dropping capabilities not working as expected?

Tags: docker, linux-capabilities

From this docker doc page - https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities

> Processes (like web servers) that just need to bind on a port below
> 1024 do not need to run as root: they can just be granted the
> net_bind_service.

Below is my Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
#FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
LABEL description="This is hello-docker app"
LABEL version="1.0.0-snapshot"

#distro specific things before application specific things
#this will be cached, so you have to build with --no-cache option
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk

#just for demo - installed for demo
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN sudo sh -c 'echo root:root | chpasswd'


#ENV APP_HOME /usr/apps
ENV APP_HOME=/myapps
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME

#with customuser/appuser
RUN groupadd  appgroup && useradd -g appgroup appuser
#RUN groupadd -g 999 appgroup && useradd -r -u 999 -g appgroup appuser
#COPY --chown=appuser:appgroup hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /

COPY --chown=nobody:nogroup hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $APP_HOME

#documenting that the application exposes these ports
EXPOSE 8080 8081

#switching to non-root user. This is recommended for security purpose
#USER appuser
USER nobody

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l

# this command (bash) can be overwritten while running the image using arguments
#CMD ["bash"]

#ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
#CMD ["exec java  -jar hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dserver.port=80",  "./hello-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

1. As, it can be observed - i have switched to `nobody` user. This user is NOT root. So this user should not be able to bind to any port below 1024 and the container should fail at startup. But it's succeeding and i am able to access the web application on port 80. WHY.
2. I tried removing the capability explicitly - but still, the container is succeeding. WHY STILL????
   `docker run --name hello-docker -it --cap-drop net_bind_service  --rm -p 80:80 dockerdemo/hello-docker:1.0`
   The container ran successfully even after removing net bind service capability.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit -
Q3 - related to above.
The same docker security doc mentioned above points to this page - https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/oci/caps/defaults.go#L6-L19
What does default here refer to:> Capabilities granted to any user (root or Not root) or only root user. If only root, then what are capabilities granted to non-root user. None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the capability to bind to privileged ports. What has changed is that unprivileged ports don't start at the normal 1024 inside of containers. Instead it's set to 0 so every port is unprivileged. The privileged restriction doesn't make sense for a single user / single application environment.

See this PR for more details:
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41030